# Interacting with generic types and boxing/unboxing

Tags: generics, f#, covariance

I'm interested in understanding more about how the following is possible. Given a collection constrained to type obj and the following function:

```
let myList = new ResizeArray<obj>()

let addToMyListTuple<'a> (item : string * 'a) =
    let boxed = box item
    let unboxed = unbox<string * 'a> boxed
    let item1 = match unboxed with first, _ -> first
    Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" item1)
    myList.Add(boxed)
```

Interacting with these 2 gives the expected results and the string part of the tuple can be consumed regardless of the associated type in the second part.

```
addToMyListTuple("integer", 3)
addToMyListTuple("float", 3.0)
addToMyListTuple("string", "string")
addToMyListTuple("tuple", (3, "integer"))
```

However, what I was hoping would be possible was this where I would be able to interact with items in the list at a later time and unbox the obj in such a way that accessing the string part of the tuple would be possible.

```
myList
|> Seq.iter(fun x ->
    let unboxed = unbox<string * 'a> x
    let item1 = match unboxed with first, _ -> first
    Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" item1)
)
```

Running this gives me the compile time warning

```
This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type 'obj'.
```

and the runtime exception

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.Object]'.
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `addToMyTupleList<'a>`, the concrete type of `'a` is statically known by the compiler (that is, you're calling `addToMyTupleList<int>`, `addToMyTupleList<float>`, etc.).  By contrast, when you're trying to do the unboxing within `Seq.iter`, you're hoping that `'a` will be determined based on the runtime type of the argument, which isn't how the F# type system works.

As I see it, you have a few options:

1. Use a type test, as Daniel suggests.
2. Instead of storing the raw values in the list, store the outputs you want to generate (that is, use a `string list` where you call `sprintf` as you're putting things in.
3. Be a bit more precise with the types you're storing in your list.  Encode the type `∃'a.string * 'a` (that is, it's a pair consisting of a string and an `'a`, for some unknown `'a`) and store a list of these.  In a language like Haskell this isn't too bad, but faithfully encoding it in F# is ugly/confusing:

   ```
   type ExPair<'x> =
       abstract Apply : string * 'a -> 'x
   type ExPair =
       abstract ForAll : ExPair<'x> -> 'x

   let pack p = { new ExPair with 
                       member __.ForAll<'x>(e:ExPair<'x>) : 'x = e.Apply p }

   let myList = [pack ("integer", 3)
                 pack ("float", 3.0)
                 pack ("string", "string")
                 pack ("tuple", (3, "integer"))]

   myList
   |> List.map (fun e ->
       e.ForAll { new ExPair<string> with member __.Apply(s,x) = sprintf "%s,%A" s x })
   ```

Comment: Thanks! It might be less concise than a Haskell version but I find this to be a very interesting and elegant solution to the problem and I love seeing new ways to leverage object notation!

Answer (score 2):

If you show more of what you're trying to do there may be a better way to make it polymorphic (e.g., unions), but you *could* do this with type tests:

```
let tuples = ResizeArray()
let addToTuples (k, v) = tuples.Add(k, box v)
addToTuples ("int", 3)
addToTuples ("float", 3.0)
addToTuples ("string", "foo")
addToTuples ("tuple", (3, "int"))
addToTuples ("option", Some 1)

tuples
|> Seq.iter (fun (s, x) ->
    printf "String: %s, Value: " s
    match x with
    | :? int as i -> printfn "%d" i
    | :? float as d -> printfn "%f" d
    | :? string as s -> printfn "%s" s
    | :? (int * string) as t -> let x, y = t in printfn "(%d, %s)" x y
    | _ -> printfn "{%A}"  x
)
```